# How to use generated and encoded key in jce

Tags: java, encryption, key

If I generate a key like this:

```
SecretKey aesKey    = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES").generateKey();
```

Then decode it:

```
System.out.println("used key: " + aesKlic.getEncoded());
```

And now I want to use it for decryption(after exiting program and starting again).
Obviously, something like this does not work:

```
SecretKey aesKey    = javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@[B@6c6e70c7;
```

if the string at the end is decoded key.

Answer (score 1):

`getEncoded()` returns a `byte[]`, whose implementation of `toString()` is not what you are looking for.

You are perhaps either looking for a hex, or a base64 representation of your key.

For hex, you can use [Hex.encodeHex(byte[])](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html)

For base64 - [Base64.encodeBase64String(byte[])](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html)

(both from [apache commons-codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/))

When you need to restored the string-encoded key (e.g. when you start your program again), you will have to call the decoding equivalents of the above methods (they in the same classes).